# Identifying certain sequences and their durations from data.table columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have boolean data in a data.table on treatment starts and ends. Not all starts qualify, so there exists a dummy for that, too. What I want to do is to identify treatment episodes that start with a qualified_start == TRUE and end at the next end == TRUE, and then determine their duration in days and add it on the row when treatment ends. Furthermore, I wish to group by person_id, so that the sequences are unique to each person. There might be any number of observations per treatment episode.

Sample data:

```
person_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
start <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
end <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE , FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
qualified_start <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)

dates = as.Date(c('2023-08-01', '2023-08-02', '2023-08-03', '2023-08-04', '2023-08-05', '2023-07-31','2023-08-01', '2023-08-02', '2023-08-03', '2023-08-04'))

dt <- data.table(dates, person_id, start, end, qualified_start)
```

```
        dates person_id start   end qualified_start
 1: 2023-08-01         1  TRUE  TRUE            TRUE
 2: 2023-08-02         1  TRUE FALSE            TRUE
 3: 2023-08-03         1 FALSE  TRUE           FALSE
 4: 2023-08-04         1  TRUE  TRUE            TRUE
 5: 2023-08-05         1  TRUE FALSE           FALSE
 6: 2023-07-31         2  TRUE FALSE            TRUE
 7: 2023-08-01         2 FALSE FALSE           FALSE
 8: 2023-08-02         2 FALSE  TRUE           FALSE
 9: 2023-08-03         2  TRUE  TRUE           FALSE
10: 2023-08-04         2  TRUE  TRUE            TRUE
```

Desired output:

```
         dates person_id start   end qualified_start duration
 1: 2023-08-01         1  TRUE  TRUE            TRUE        0
 2: 2023-08-02         1  TRUE FALSE            TRUE       NA
 3: 2023-08-03         1 FALSE  TRUE           FALSE        1
 4: 2023-08-04         1  TRUE  TRUE            TRUE        0
 5: 2023-08-05         1  TRUE FALSE           FALSE       NA
 6: 2023-07-31         2  TRUE FALSE            TRUE       NA
 7: 2023-08-01         2 FALSE FALSE           FALSE       NA
 8: 2023-08-02         2 FALSE  TRUE           FALSE        2
 9: 2023-08-03         2  TRUE  TRUE           FALSE       NA
10: 2023-08-04         2  TRUE  TRUE            TRUE        0
```

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problems, which can be solved easily with a simple `for` loop and `if` conditions, I find it best to develop and maintain a small Rcpp function. I use `cppFunction` here but you should prefer storing the source code in a separate file and not as a character sting.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(person_id, start, end, qualified_start)

library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('NumericVector foo(const LogicalVector start,
                               const LogicalVector end) {
        R_xlen_t n = start.length();
        NumericVector d(n);
        double count = NA_REAL;
        for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) { 
         count++;
         if (start[i] == 1) {
           count = 0;
         }
         if (end[i] == 1) {
           d[i] = count;
           count = NA_REAL;
         }
         if (end[i] == 0) {
           d[i] = NA_REAL;
         }
        }
        return d;
    }')

DT[, duration := foo(qualified_start, end), by = person_id]
#   person_id start   end qualified_start duration
# 1:         1  TRUE  TRUE            TRUE        0
# 2:         1  TRUE FALSE            TRUE       NA
# 3:         1 FALSE  TRUE           FALSE        1
# 4:         1  TRUE  TRUE            TRUE        0
# 5:         1  TRUE FALSE           FALSE       NA
# 6:         2  TRUE FALSE            TRUE       NA
# 7:         2 FALSE FALSE           FALSE       NA
# 8:         2 FALSE  TRUE           FALSE        2
# 9:         2  TRUE  TRUE           FALSE       NA
#10:         2  TRUE  TRUE            TRUE        0
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table`-native alternative:

```r
library(data.table)
dt[, grp := cumsum(qualified_start), by = .(person_id)
  ][, duration := fcase(
      end & qualified_start,  0,
      end & cumsum(end) <= 1, as.numeric(dates - dates[1]),
      rep(TRUE, .N),          NA_real_
    ), by = .(person_id, grp)][]
#          dates person_id  start    end qualified_start   grp duration
#         <Date>     <num> <lgcl> <lgcl>          <lgcl> <int>    <int>
#  1: 2023-08-01         1   TRUE   TRUE            TRUE     1        0
#  2: 2023-08-02         1   TRUE  FALSE            TRUE     2       NA
#  3: 2023-08-03         1  FALSE   TRUE           FALSE     2        1
#  4: 2023-08-04         1   TRUE   TRUE            TRUE     3        0
#  5: 2023-08-05         1   TRUE  FALSE           FALSE     3       NA
#  6: 2023-07-31         2   TRUE  FALSE            TRUE     1       NA
#  7: 2023-08-01         2  FALSE  FALSE           FALSE     1       NA
#  8: 2023-08-02         2  FALSE   TRUE           FALSE     1        2
#  9: 2023-08-03         2   TRUE   TRUE           FALSE     1       NA
# 10: 2023-08-04         2   TRUE   TRUE            TRUE     2        0
```